# Spanning tree of directed graph with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree, subgraph

I have a directed graph G in networkx and I want to get the minimum spanning tree of it.
I do:

```
 T = nx.algorithms.minimum_spanning_tree( G.to_undirected()  )
```

This is undirected and I would like to restore the directions but I don't know how to do it.
I tried:

```
G[T.edges()]
```

This last line looks very pythonic but this is not the way networkx works, apparently...
Does anyone knows how to do it?

In other words: How can I get the subgraph of a directed tree given the (undirected) edges ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the edges in `G` that appear in the MST `T` with a simple comprehension:

```
E = set(T.edges())  # optimization
[e for e in G.edges() if e in E or reversed(e) in E]
```

You can then build a new graph from this.

Comment: An to keep weights: `[(i,o,w) for i,o,w in G.edges_iter(data=True) if ((i,o) in T.edges() or (o,i) in T.edges())]`

Comment: __Update__ `G.edges_iter` has been removed in networkx-2.