# Minimal directed spanning tree in Networkx

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

Is there any implementation of minimal directed spanning trees (MDST) in networkx, one of the most famous algorithms to find MDSTs is [Edmond's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm), but I don't find its implementation with networkx. Can any one help with that?

Note that this question is different from this [qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537137/spanning-tree-of-directed-graph-with-networkx), because in our case we want to find an MDST not an MST of the undirected version of the graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

networkx has an implementation of Edmond's algorithm:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.branchings.Edmonds.html